# Java keystrokes

Tags: java, android, awtrobot

I'm trying to write what I was expecting to be a simple program. I wrote an android app that sends keystrokes over WiFi to a paired PC. The PC decodes these and creates keystroke events. All of that works fine. I'm able to pass data from the tablet, decode it and create a keystroke event in Java using the Robot class. The issue I run into is that some apps don't recognize the keystrokes, they will respond fine if I have a USB keyboard hooked up but robot.keyPress doesn't get me any response.

If I have a program like notepad selected it works but some of our in-house applications don't pick up the keystrokes. Apparently I need a way to simulate the keystroke events on a lower level but I can't seem to find any way that works for me.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If they are your in-house applications, why don't you start by seeing what's different about them?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I started a new IT position. I inherited a lot of problems from the last guy and this company only has one IT position to I can't ask anyone how this stuff works, normally not an issue but I am still working at 2am my time so I really don;t have time to dive that deep into every problem. My hope is that someone has seen this before and can point to a possible solution and save me a little time.

Comment: Are you sure that this applications are the currently active window and that some kind of textfield is selected?

Comment: There's no text field per se. The keyboard input is used to navigate the UI. As I understand it the program is just watching for keystrokes. It's all written in C which is outside my wheelhouse I'm afraid. I'm working through it but it takes time and I'm still unclear how a lot of it works. My problem is, it will respond to keystrokes from a physical keyboard but not from Java. If I can find a way to completely simulate keystrokes, either in Java, or some scripting language like Perl or Racket, that should get me up and running.